# I want an imageView image to be equal to a CollectionView image When it is tapped?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView with a random image in each cell called imageCell below. And I have another imageView called mainImage. I want mainImage to equal the image selected in the CollectionView when it is tapped imageCell. My attempt does make the imageCell equal to mainImage image but it's really slow to do so and it will only do it once. Any other solution or fix?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")

    // This is my attempt below 
    if cell.isSelected {
       mainImage.image = cell.imageCell.image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to use `didSelectItemAt` to deal with the cell being tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` instead, as it gets called every time a user makes a selection on an index of the collectionView. so try the following:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     let image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
     mainImage.image = image
}
```